# Resizing browser won't show responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a website that has a responsive design with all its values in an external stylesheet. On mobile devices it works perfectly, but resizing the browser does nothing and I'm completely stumped.

http://appearly.co.nf/

Comment: You have javascript errors on this page. jquery.flexslider-min.js is not loading (check console on chrome with ctrl+shift+j)

Comment: How can I fix that? The module runs fine which means that the author of the script did poor coding and it's not an error on my part.

Comment: It looks you have Jquery Conflict. Use NoConflict

Comment: try putting all <script> together at the head, with jquery.min being at the top

Comment: Not sure what NoConflict is. I'll take a look.

Comment: Also, I can't put scripts in header. It's a requirement by the client that it goes in the footer.

Comment: Even in your Contact page, your flexslider script is executing, which is not needed in that page.

Comment: I did not notice that! I've yet to polish the site, however thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by changing your media query to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) { }
```

// edit

In case this comment is causing you confusion, replace first line in your **responsive_stylesheet.css** file.

Currently, you have `@media (max-device-width: 980px) {` replace this with `@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {`.

Comment: This website has all the responsive design in an external stylesheet (1st line says this) OP.

Comment: Yes, I know. The first line in that file should be as above (minus the end curly bracket).